# Wedge product of entries of a matrix & Volume form of the Siegel metric

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-forms, siegel-modular-forms

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ square matrix, and $\omega(A)=\bigwedge\limits_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}$ be the wedge product of its entries. Then, if $B=UA=(b_{ij})$ for some square matrix $U$, I think one can calculate $\omega(B)$ by treating each column of $A$ as an $n\times 1$ vector and using $\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^nb_{ij}=\det U\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ij}$, and then wedge all of them together to get $\omega(B)=(\det U)^n\omega(A)$. I am not sure that this is the proper way to do it, as I cannot extend this method to the case of symmetric matrices where the entries are no more independent and hence cannot be treated as separate columns to be wedged together later to get $\omega(B)$.

i.e. Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix and $\omega(A)=\bigwedge\limits_{i\leq j}a_{ij}$ be the wedge product of its independent entries. Let $B=UAU^T$, for some square matrix $U$. How to calculate $\omega(B)?$

And also in general, is there a reference that treats these wedging of entries of a matrix?

The specific use I have in mind is derivation of the volume form of Siegel metric on the Siegel upper half space $\mathbb{H}_g=\{\tau=x+iy\in\mathrm{Sym}(g,\mathbb{C})\mid y>0\}$ where the metric is given by $\mathrm{d}s^2=\mathrm{trace}(y^{-1}\mathrm{d}\tau\, y^{-1}\mathrm{d} \bar{\tau})$ and the volume form is given by $\mathrm{d}v_g=\frac{1}{(\det y)^{g+1}}\bigwedge\limits_{i\leq j}(\mathrm{d}x_{ij}\wedge\mathrm{d}y_{ij})$. Can we derive $\mathrm{d}v_g$ from $\mathrm{d}s^2$ by $\mathrm{d}v_g=\omega(y^{-1}\mathrm{d}\tau\, y^{-1}\mathrm{d} \bar{\tau})$?

Comment: Might be easier to just observe that the left $G$-invariant measure on $G/K=PK/K\cong P$ in an Iwasawa decomposition has to be the left Haar measure on $P$.